# Consuming an LTI link from Desire2Learn

Tags: authentication, desire2learn, lti

We are currently using D2L version 9.1 and have set up an external tool provider in the LMS.  I believe that we have properly configured the endpoint, since it redirects me to the endpoint I expected and contains the LTI-specific payloads.

However, as per the [LTI Specification](http://www.imsglobal.org/lti/v1p1pd/ltiIMGv1p1pd.html#_Toc309649685), we do not see the standard OAUTH payloads of oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, oauth_timestamp.

How would we go about authenticating an LTI link from Desire2Learn to make sure that it is properly secured?

Answer (score 0):

The LTI parameters other than security may be sent if the key or secret fields aren't set when the External Learning Tool was set up.  That would result in missing oath fields, but, other fields present.

Is there a chance that either key or secret are missing from the link or the configured tool provider?

You can use the "Preview Request Details" in the External Learning Tool Setup page to see what is going to go out.

In my tests if I didn't set the key the preview showed:

```
<form method="post" id="LtiRequestForm" name="LtiRequestForm" action="http://test.com" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="launch_presentation_locale" value="EN-CA__">
<input type="hidden" name="lti_message_type" value="basic-lti-launch-request">
<input type="hidden" name="lti_version" value="LTI-1p0">
<input type="hidden" name="resource_link_description" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="resource_link_id" value="testserver">
<input type="hidden" name="resource_link_title" value="Test Title">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_contact_email" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_description" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_guid" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="basiclti_submit" value="Launch Endpoint with BasicLTI Data">
</form>
```

But when I did set the key the preview shows:

```
<form method="post" id="LtiRequestForm" name="LtiRequestForm" action="http://test.com" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="launch_presentation_locale" value="EN-CA__">
<input type="hidden" name="lti_message_type" value="basic-lti-launch-request">
<input type="hidden" name="lti_version" value="LTI-1p0">
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_callback" value="about:blank">
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_consumer_key" value="asdf">
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_nonce" value="383531779">
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature" value="8G/2Kkkt1ik3Yh6QdNvZd769mug=">
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature_method" value="HMAC-SHA1">
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_timestamp" value="1325880893">
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_version" value="1.0">
<input type="hidden" name="resource_link_description" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="resource_link_id" value="testserver">
<input type="hidden" name="resource_link_title" value="Test Title">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_contact_email" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_description" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_guid" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="basiclti_submit" value="Launch Endpoint with BasicLTI Data">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.  I did configure the tool provider with a key/secret, but I didn't see a way to connect the link to the tool provider.   

As a test, I used "Link Key/Secret".  The oauth parameters came through then.